# Issue with Rails routes and models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 models - User model and Profile model. I have setup the relationship as follows:

```
class User
  has_one :profile
end

class Profile
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I have a profiles controller with 4 actions - new create edit and update. Once the User signs up or logs in he is redirected to the New action in the Profiles controller. From here how do I create a profile for that user? Specifically what should I have in my New action and Create action. Right now the route for the new action is just profiles/new which doesn't capture the Users params. I am trying to do this but its failing.

Profiles Controller

```
def new
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @profile = @user.build_profile
  end

  def create
    @profile = current_user.build_profile(params[:profile])
    if @profile.save
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      render new
    end
  end
```

Comment: How is it falling and how your routes looks like?

Comment: It says cant find User without id. Essentially the route for profile#new is localhost:3000/profiles/new. There is no user id being passed here. Not sure if I should be changing the route. I am using devise for authentication so its creating a user and being redirected to profiles#new. I dont know what to do from here on.

Comment: I guess what I am trying to figure out is if I need to capture the Users id in the new action. Can I do something like this? 
def new
@profile = current_user.build_profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `new` action in the profile controller doesn't need to get the `id` of the user from the params.
So your controller would be like this

```
def new
  @user = current_user
  @profile = @user.build_profile
end

def create
  @profile = current_user.build_profile(params[:profile])
  if @profile.save
    redirect_to current_user
  else
    render new
  end
end
```

actually sending the `id` of the user to the `new` action could be a security hole as I could send the `id` of another user and create a profile for some other user in the system, which shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: Now that I done some research I came across this concept of a singular nested resource. Wouldn't that be the preferred way to do things? I am just going to have to use cancan for authorization but I think the routes make more sense now. /users/id/profile/new or /users/id/profile/edit. Any thoughts?

Comment: it would definitely make more sense but you will have the same issue that a user may send the id of another user and you would still have to use `current_user` instead of getting the user `id` from the params, so use nested resources but still use the `current_user` in the case for `profile`

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using `User.find(params[:id]` in your new action.

Just like in your create action below, you should be getting the `User` through `current_user`.

Is there more to the problem than not being able to properly fetch the `User`?